# Storing regular expression result in vector<string> using <regex>

Tags: c++, regex

I am extracting a line of text from a string using regular expressions. I am storing them in a vector to used later. My problem is when I access the text from the vector nothing comes out. I noticed when displaying the string using cout that it will not display anything unless I used endl after it. I noticed as well that the example given by C++ deliberately cout's endl to display the regex_search result http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/regex/regex_search/.

Here's the snippet of my code in question:

```
while (regex_search(s, m, e)) {

     for (auto x:m){

        blocks.push_back(x);
     }

     s = m.suffix().str();
}

for (auto i: blocks){
        cout << i;
}
```

When I do

```
for (auto i: blocks){
        cout << i << endl;
}
```

it displays the contents.

Answer (score 1):

`cout` may cache. `endl` flushes the cache as `cout.flush();`
Put `cout.flush();` after last loop to see what output with it.

Comment: My problem is tyring to use the string in other places. like sprintf. I'm getting the problem where the string is not being accessed

Comment: @user1721803 `where the string is not being accessed`
What do you mean?